# Passing a big list of options from controller to view

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, performance, model-view-controller

I am having a huge list of items (15000) to be populated on the items drop down in the front end. Hence I have made an AJAX call (triggered upon a selection of a Company) and this AJAX call to made to an action method in the Controller and this action method populates the list of service items and returns it back to the AJAX call via response. This is where my AJAX call is failing. If i have about 100 - 500 items, the ajax call works. How do I fix this issue?

Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetCompanyInfo(int Name)
        {
            try
            {
                List<SelectList> lists = new List<SelectList>();

                //This yields about 100 - 20000 items depending on the company
                var serviceItem = cache.getServiceItems(Name).ToList();
                serviceItem.Insert(0, null);
                ViewBag.SelectedServiceItem = new SelectList(serviceItem, "ID", "Name", model.SelectedServiceItem);

                //there are some lists here that not shown for the purpose of demonstation 
                lists.Add(ViewBag.SelectedServiceItem);

                return Json(lists);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error(e);
                return null;
            }


        }
```

AJAX code:

```
$("#selectedCompany").change(function () {
            $("#dashSpinner").show();
            var rule = {
                name: $("#selectedCompany").val(),
            }
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: rule,
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCompanyInfo")',
                success: function (lists) {

                    $.each(lists[1], function (i, serviceItem) {
                        $("#SelectedServiceItem").append('<option value="' + serviceItem.Value + '">' +
                         serviceItem.Text + '</option>');
                    });
                    $.each(lists[7], function (i, product) {
                        $("#SelectedProduct").append('<option value="' + product.Value + '">' +
                         product.Text + '</option>');
                    });

                    $("#dashSpinner").hide();


                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: Why does the ajax call fail? Does the request timeout?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a request timeout.

Comment: what error do you have? did you confirm that you have in fact 15K items returned from your api?

Comment: I am getting the following error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: I am using a jquery selector for the drop down called "select2" and i am looking into the documentation. It looks like there can be a performance issue for loading more that 1500 items

Comment: IMHO, "performance issue" is the _least_ of your problems. What do you expect an **end user** to do with _1500_ choices?

Comment: An error code 500 strongly suggests, that you should set a breakpoint and debug your server side code. That will give you an indication on what fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why : This issue is occur due to the "content-length" (payload) pass over the network(HTTP Request)

Solution : There is two way you can solve these issue

1. Setting Content-Length at your code level

   `lists.Add(ViewBag.SelectedServiceItem);
     var jsonResult = Json(lists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
     return jsonResult`;
2. At the Config-Level in your web.config

   `<configuration> 
        <system.web.extensions>
            <scripting>
              <webServices>
                 <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
              </webServices> 
           </scripting>
        </system.web.extensions>
   </configuration>`

Note : I will suggest to configure it at config level

Thank You

Comment: I tried to use the second solution and it did not work. The first solution however worked for me. Thanks a lot.